# Display information from a GeoJson in a popup (LEAFLET)

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, web-deployment

I am writing a program for my Company that owns Trails. The program displays a webmap with a long trail (connecting all the trails) as it should. I also have markers displayed on each trailhead by reading coordinates from a GeoJson Array. I want to bind a popup to each marker that ATLEAST displays the name of each trailhead in the popups. I have tried lots of things but nothing is working. I will link my current HTML file and the GeoJson file now.

[GeoJson TrailHeaders File](http://www.mediafire.com/file/8884gn49n2s89mo/trailheads.js)

[Index.Html](http://www.mediafire.com/file/9mm2bc3jn31z3lu/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the `GeoJSON()` function options:

```
var trailheadsLayer = L.geoJson(trailheads, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
        console.log(feature.properties);
        content = "Name: " + feature.properties.name + "<br>Abbreviation: " + feature.properties.abbreviati; 
        layer.bindPopup(content);
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

The `content` string can be modified with the json properties you need. Be careful and format the string as an HTML element.

You can see here a [live version](https://plnkr.co/edit/a5g7AdHQhp04JJ2wuS9s?p=preview) of your map.

PS. Hope it's not too late for the answer.